# How to get PSF Settings in an AS400 Server using Java

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400, jtopen

I am a newbie in this site but I know anyone here can help me on this problem that I have now. I used to program Java using JDK7 and now I am facing this JTOpen API for AS400-Java interface but my problem now is how to get all the PSF Setting of my Device Description of a certain Writer?

Thanks in advance guys....

Please help.....

Comment: Maybe a dumb question ... but what are you referring to by 'PSF'?

Comment: Presuming you mean Print Services Facility, could you describe what you're trying to do?  Set up a printer?  Retrieve printer attributes (like a utility might want)?  Print something?

Comment: Yeah ur right Buck, I would like to get the Print Services Facility Services Settings (i.e. values for "IPDS Pass through", "Release Timer", "Restart Timer", etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the print API's at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/apis/print1a.htm

If you can find an API that provides the information you are looking for, it shouldn't be hard to invoke it from java.

Answer (score 0):

Some of that information is available in com.ibm.as400.access.PrintObject but not all.  I'd write a wrapper program/procedure over the Retrieve AFP Information (QPQRAFPI) API, and use JT400 to call that.  The equivalent CL command is WRKPSFCFG.

Comment: yeah,,,that is right Buck, but is there a way to get the data when I use "DSPPSFCFG PSFCFG()"? since that command will display all the psfcfg setting and is there a way that I can get all those data being presented by that command?

Comment: I am primarily an ILE RPG programmer; Java is not my strength.  I would write an ILE RPG program that calls the API and then write a Java program that uses JT400 to call the RPG, which would pass back any parameters needed.  I were were forced to do it all in Java, I'd get the JT400 source and write a PSFAttrs similar to AFPResourceAttrs.  Then I could do it all with a JT400 PrintObject.

Comment: so maybe i just need a PrintObject exploration.....but I have done it before maybe gonna have to try it again this time....thanks a lot guys....